# $.post function doesn't append changes to the textarea

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So I'm new to Javascript and after searching a long time I did not find the answer I was looking for (maybe because I don't have the right terms)

So here's my script:

```
function changeStyle() {
    var type = $('select[name=style_website]').val();
    var numwebsite = $('select[name=style_website]').attr('data-numwebsite');

    $.post("getstyle",{'type': type,'numwebsite': numwebsite},
        function(retour){
            $('.websitestyle_js').val(retour);
        });
}
```

And here's my html:

```
<strong><?php echo "Modify your style";?></strong>
<select onchange="changeStyle()" style="float: right;" name="style_website" data-numwebsite="<?php echo $numwebsite;?>">
    <option value="style" selected>Your style</option>
    <option value="mini">Mini</option>
    <option value="bmw">Bmw</option>
</select>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>websites/modificationStyle?numwebsite=<?php echo $numwebsite;?>">
    <div class="well">
        <p><strong><?php echo "Code Editor";?></strong></p>
        <textarea name="websitestyle" class="websitestyle_js" id="code1"><?php echo $websitedata['websitestyle'];?></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success form-control m-b"><?php echo "Modify Style";?></button>
</form>
```

What I wanted to do is change the content of my textarea depending on the select, every time the user click on a different option it is suppose to change the textarea. The problem is that it doesn't change anything, so I was wondering if my syntax was wrong or if I was missing something.

I printed "retour" with alert() and it contains the data that I want to append to the textarea, so it doesn't come from that. And I also try to add this line:

```
$('.websitestyle_js').val('test');
```

Jut alone at the end of my html to see if it was a syntax error, but it changes the textarea.

Thank you for your answers.

EDIT1 (result of console.log as asked):

[console.log(retour)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVOrd.png)

EDIT2 (what it looks like at the end for those of you who are confused):

[code_editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTJOS.png)

Comment: Your syntax looks fine. Have you checked that the AJAX request is actually being completed successfully? The fact that the textarea is not being updated implies that it's not. Check the status in the console.

Comment: check the browser developer console and see any error is there or not?

Comment: why is the `select` outside the `form`?

Comment: There is no error on the console, and when I go to network, the script access the function that returns the value that is needed to change the textarea. The select is not part of the form, it is just here to show the different style. I don't need to get the value of the select because I'm only interested by the textarea.

Comment: what is the value of `console.log(retour);`  show us

Comment: Did you want to put the whole `CSS` code as a value of `textarea`?

Comment: And what you want it to look like?

Comment: Well I would like to change the content of the textarea everytime I select a different option. There is 3 different style.

Answer (score 0):

Try workaround via jquery on change. Here is a demo that changes textarea when you change select

```
<strong><?php echo "Modify your style";?></strong>
<select style="float: right;" name="style_website" data-numwebsite="numwebsite">
<option value="style" selected>Your style</option>
<option value="mini">Mini</option>
<option value="bmw">Bmw</option>
</select>
<form method="post">
<div class="well">
    <p><strong><?php echo "Code Editor";?></strong></p>
    <textarea name="websitestyle" class="websitestyle_js" id="code1"></textarea>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success form-control m-b">Modify Style</button>
</form>
```

JS

```
$('select[name=style_website]').on('change', function (e) {
var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
var valueSelected = this.value;
$('.websitestyle_js').val(valueSelected);
});
```

Maybe this is not really that you need, but it generally answers your question "What I wanted to do is change the content of my textarea depending on the select, every time the user click on a different option it is suppose to change the textarea".

[Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Reset5/9k8z7Lv7/1/)

Comment: Well it works in the case I wanted to use the value of the select options to change what's in the textarea. But I want to use other values, that are not in the html, that's why I need $.post

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>   
 function changeStyle() {
        var type = $('select[name=style_website]').val();
        var numwebsite = $('select[name=style_website]').attr('data-numwebsite');

        $.post("getstyle.php",{'type': type,'numwebsite': numwebsite},
            function(retour){
                $('.websitestyle_js').val(retour);
            });
    }
</script>  

<strong><?php echo "Modify your style";?></strong>
<select onchange="changeStyle()" style="float: right;" name="style_website" data-numwebsite="<?php echo $numwebsite;?>">
    <option value="style" selected>Your style</option>
    <option value="mini">Mini</option>
    <option value="bmw">Bmw</option>
</select>
<form method="post" action="websites/modificationStyle?numwebsite=<?php echo $numwebsite;?>">
    <div class="well">
        <p><strong><?php echo "Code Editor";?></strong></p>
        <textarea name="websitestyle" class="websitestyle_js" id="code1"><?php echo $websitedata['websitestyle'];?></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success form-control m-b"><?php echo "Modify Style";?></button>
</form>
```

Try this...It is working..

Comment: The only thing you change is you put the script before the html, right?

Comment: in $.post() i add filename properly i.e. "getstyle.php"...also removed <?php echo base_url();?> from form action attribute....and crosschecked whether response is coming back from getstyle.php or not..thats it

Answer (score 0):

Try console logging retour, maybe you should use responseText, another option is to try html(retour) instead of val

Answer (score 0):

It was CodeMirror which is what I use to have the Code style that was creating a conflict. I fixed my problem, thank you all for you anwers